# Create advance report in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am working with `magento` and `I want to create report module in magento`.

Default Magento reports are ok but not satisfied my need that why I want to create new one

My requirement for order report

> Sr  | Prodduct name | Size 1 | Size 2  | Color 1  | Color 2 | Price |
>   Quantity Ordered

*Note : Size and color more then one its product attribute and also need to export in csv*

Please provide me full details not short

Thanks
Jitendra

Comment: are you want need order item report ya order report

Comment: order item report with different colors and size (Its means sales report item wise with different color and size )

Comment: ok,you can this http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/custom-reports-magento...then it will  modify in code

Comment: I am using this but need to add colors and size column (both are dynamic more then 1) how can do ? and what is the magento query ?

Comment: please check this url for join query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277816/magento-get-collection-of-order-items-for-a-product-collection-filtered-by-an-a